# Why is my Maven file structure different from all tutorials?

Tags: eclipse, maven, selenium

I have Eclipse Neon, with latest Maven, TestNG and Selenium.
I have reviewed several tutorials on how to create a maven project and the file structure in the tutorials is not what I am getting.  Why am I missing several files?

note:

[This is what tutorials show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWQx8.png)
[This is what I get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yq0a3.png)

Comment: Can you share what is mavenTestNG1 & mavenTestNGOne?

Comment: Did you create the Maven structure on disk first (using an artifact) and then used "File -> Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects" to  load the project into Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Both are same . Only view is different . You can change it by going to eclipse->window->show view  , and choosing the view you want

Answer (score 0):

Here are some points for your help:

1. Install the maven plugin through Eclipse.
2. Set the Environment variables, e.g. JAVA_HOME, MAVEN_HOME & add the required paths.
3. From command-line, check "java -version" & "mvn -version".
4. If this 2 commands shows proper info, you are set to write your first maven project.
5. Create a new project as maven project with all the required information.
6. On completion you will find a similar directory structure with "src/main/java",  "src/test/java" & JRE Library along with pom.xml.
7. Open the "pom.xml", provide all the dependencies, e.g. Selenium, TestNG & save.
8. You will find all the dependencies being listed in "Maven Dependencies" and you will also find testng.xml
9. Place the "testng.xml" in the location you specified in "pom.xml"
10. Your project structure should be looking similar now.

Let me know if this helps you.